# Call a php from another php using ajax

Tags: javascript, php, ajax

I'm trying to call a php from ajax, so I wrote this on my first page (index.php):

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function valid(id) {
    var element = document.getElementById(id);

    $.ajax({
        url: 'valid.php',
        type:'POST',
    data:
    {
        url: element.children[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue
    },
    success: function(msg)
    {
        console.log('done 1');
    }
    });
}
</script>
```

and here is my second one (valid.php):

```
<script type="text/javascript">
console.log('done 2');
</script>
<?php
if (isset($_GET['url']))
{
    try
    {
        $bdd = new PDO('mysql:host=host;dbname=dbname;charset=utf8', 'id', 'password');
        $bdd->exec("INSERT INTO sometable (url) 
VALUES (".$_GET['url'].");");
    }
    catch (Exception $e)
    {
        die();
    }
}
?>
```

But when I call my function, it doesn't seem to call valid.php even if the console show "done 1", "done 2" doesn't appear anywhere by the way and the database stay unchanged, like valid.php just doesn't run.

How may I fix that? Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Since you are using POST, you need to retrieve your data using $_POST rather than $_GET.

Answer (score 0):

In valid.php if you are expecting `isset($_GET['url'])` which is a GET parameter but your AJAX request is sent via POST. You should change that to `isset($_POST['url'])`.

Regarding the `console.log('done 2');` on valid.php it won't get executed unless you append that to the body of index.php and evaluate that specific script but it is redundant because `console.log('done 1');` refers to the completion of valid.php request.

Edit: On your insertion query you have `$_GET['url']` and it should be `$_POST['url']`.

Comment: Thank for the response, I didn't saw that. I changed this but it's still the same, the database still doesn't change.

Comment: @Ticki Check the edit I made to the answer it should help you.